# In a Javascript generated list, how to add custom atributes to the <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have a javascript that generates a list for me. This all works. The problem is in the `<a>` tag. In this tag I want to ad more attributes like `data-i="2"` Putting an extra attribute in like: `menu: f.menuCaption`, `class: f.class` or `style: f.style` works perfectly. Please see my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/mjdyW/13/

But when I want to add a new attribute like: `data-i` it doesn't work. How come? See demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/mjdyW/15/ (the second `<UL>` is the one adapted using `data-i`).

How can I make it so that I can also add/use attributes like `data-i` to the script? My end goal is to create this: `<a class="d" data-i="50" data-t="d" data-f="2" data-r="0" data-c="0" style="margin-top: -4.725em; margin-left: -4.6em; "></a>` (getting the values from the script of course)

Thank you for your time

Comment: I have no idea why you were downvoted. Since those who did so did not so much as leave any indication of what's wrong, have an upvote.

Comment: i don't know too so here is a +1 to even things out :)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote guys! I ALso have no clue for the down votes, think I explained the problem correctly, good tags, even fiddle example. I even googled before posting, though I don't know the correct search/coding terms since I just started coding with js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data-i` is not a valid identifier in JavaScript, so you need to quote it in object literals:

```
{
    'data-i': 'whatever'
}
```

and during property access:

```
whatever['data-i']
```

[See updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/mjdyW/16/)

Comment: Aahhh some simple quotes where missing :-) Thanks for the example and explanation, learned something today!